# Upgrading RailsInstaller installation via command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I'm on Windows, and am on a restricted network and cannot download the latest version of [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) (Ruby 1.9.3-p392, Rails 3.2), so I went with an older Windows version (Ruby 1.8.7-p352, Rails 3.0.7).

I have a working installation, but would like to upgrade to newer versions of both Ruby and Rails via the command line.

I've tried searching for the right resource to update via the command line, but no luck. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: The easiest way to upgrade is to uninstall the old version and reinstall the newer version. Then just reinstall any missing gems. You can't really upgrade ruby itself on Windows easily any other way.

Comment: Thanks Casper, but I simply cannot download the new version; my network will not allow me.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. It's a bit off topic, but there are many ways around such restrictions though (depending of course on what restrictions you have). You could try to use an on-line proxy (just google "free proxy server"). Perhaps that could work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) for running multiple versions of Ruby on Windows?

Evan